# How to Send POST Json and and get result from the server (display as textview)?

Tags: java, android, json, post

im beginner of java developer, how can i get response from my JSON POST server in textview? try lot of tutorial/ guide from youtube and other website, still not working, some of classes are deprecated too. anyone here help?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    btSubmit = findViewById(R.id.bt_submit);
    TextView TextViewResult;
    TextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
```

this my JSON POST coding.

```
    class AsyncT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://pltmuar.eschool.edu.my/es_api/app_login.php"); //Enter URL here
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); // here you are telling that it is a POST request, which can be changed into "PUT", "GET", "DELETE" etc.
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); // here you are setting the `Content-Type` for the data you are sending which is `application/json`
                    httpURLConnection.connect();

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("app_id", "123456");
                    jsonObject.put("username", "testparent");
                    jsonObject.put("password", "123456");
                    jsonObject.put("firebase_token", "abc123");

                    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
                    OutputStream out = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    wr.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                TextViewResult.setText();

            }


        }
```

thanks !

Comment: What do you receive now? Is there an error? I would suggest to try using RestTemplate

Comment: nothing.... how can i get response from JSON POST? for normal http POST it worked....

Answer (score 0):

> Use Volley library which is by google, for making network calls

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
```

> add above as a dependency in your app level build.gradle file

> Assuming you are making a POST request for which you are sending some params and you are receiving JSON response in return

> Inside onResponse method of Volley Post, you will get your response. You will have to parse your JSON response first according to the API response format, and then finally you can set the data from response to your text view as below:

```
yourTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("first_name").toString());
```